# Parameters after url Asp net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to have some paramaters after my website's URl.
So, mysite.com/ThisIsMyStringMessage, would show this :

> Hello, ThisIsMyStringMessage.

Of course, the view related to the action contains this :

```
Hello, @ViewBag.Message
```

And the  HomeController :

```
   public ActionResult Index(string message)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        return View();
    }
```

Edit related to comments :

@Zim, I'll have more than one controller.

@Jessee, So that's what I'm doing here, thank you, I didn't know really what I was doing.

Comment: mysite.com?message=ThisIsMyStringMessage

Comment: Will you be using any other Controllers/Actions other than HomeController/Index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the default routing, `ThisIsMyStringMessage` will be picked up as the Controller, not as an Action method parameter. You will need a custom route to be able to do this. Try the following before the default route in `Global.asax`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RootWithParameter",
    "{message}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", message = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Alternatively, access the method with `mysite.com?message=ThisIsMyStringMessage`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to take a look at your `RouteConfig.cs` or `Global.asax` to setup a route with the parameter of `message` instead of `id`. Right now it probably looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

You would need to change the url parameter to something like `{controller}/{action}/{message}` for that to work.

Also, be careful with passing strings in the URL. ASP.NET (and some modern browsers) gives you many security protections to prevent people from doing nasty stuff like XSS, but it's probably not a habit you want to create.